# PHP Hide button

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

how can i hide this background of the button?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZbO.png) <-- IMAGE OF THE BACKGROUND

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/653356422083379252/654012639847907328/download-button-png-2516x910_08c339b6.png" width="500" height="150"></button>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I don't understand your question, do you want to hide the button? It's image? On which conditions?

Comment: @Kurisu i want to hide the background of the button, https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZbO.png

i want only the image,- that white in the image is the button background-

Comment: You can try to use `imagecolortransparent()` for that, but you'd have to be careful to not remove the text inside the button as well. Documentation: http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.imagecolortransparent.php

Comment: @Kurisu the image background is transparent but the button is not, and when i try hide the button it hides the image too

Comment: why are there so many tags? Most of which seem irrelevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can play with background image on a button and position it so it takes up the button and alter the border to match the border of the image.

```css
button {
  width: 135px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/653356422083379252/654012639847907328/download-button-png-2516x910_08c339b6.png")
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

increased size:

```css
button {
  width: 245px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 275px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/653356422083379252/654012639847907328/download-button-png-2516x910_08c339b6.png")
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: how can i make it bigger without the background appears?

Comment: increase the width, height and background size

Comment: the background appears again :/
https://prnt.sc/q8z785

Comment: well I have no idea what you changed

Comment: button {
  width: 245px;
  height: 152px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 260px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/653356422083379252/654012639847907328/download-button-png-2516x910_08c339b6.png")
}

Comment: height is way too big for your image.... aspect ratio is not like that.